# media query for landscape affecting desktop

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm trying to target tablets when in landscape like so:

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1280px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
```

but this affecting desktop too, but I don't understand why it would as I thought landscape would only detect devices whose orientation can be changed.

Answer (score 0):

`landscape` only indicates ([from docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries#orientation))

> Indicates whether the viewport is in landscape (the display is wider than it is tall) or portrait (the display is taller than it is wide) mode.

You have to do some restrictions with [`media type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media) or consider using [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/docs/)

```
if (Modernizr.touch){
   // bind to touchstart, touchmove, etc and watch `event.streamId`
} else {
   // bind to normal click, mousemove, etc
}
```